# ElasticsearchTemplate retrieve big data sets

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I am new to ElasticsearchTemplate. I want to get 1000 documents from Elasticsearch based on my query.
I have used QueryBuilder to create my query , and it is working perfectly.
I have gone through the following links , which states that it is possible to achieve big data sets using scan and scroll.
[link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080251/spring-data-elasticsearch-scan-and-scroll-paged-result-is-not-working)
[link two](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/elasticsearch.misc.html)

I am trying to implement this functionality in the following section of code, which I have copy pasted from one of the link , mentioned above.
But I am getting following error :

`The type ResultsMapper is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <myInputDto>.`

`MyInputDto` is a class with `@Document` annotation in my project.
End of the day , I just want to retrieve 1000 documents from Elasticsearch. 
I tried to find `size` parameter but I think it is not supported.

```
String scrollId = esTemplate.scan(searchQuery, 1000, false);
        List<MyInputDto> sampleEntities = new ArrayList<MyInputDto>();
        boolean hasRecords = true;
        while (hasRecords) {
            Page<MyInputDto> page = esTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L,
                    new ResultsMapper<MyInputDto>() {
                        @Override
                        public Page<MyInputDto> mapResults(SearchResponse response) {
                            List<MyInputDto> chunk = new ArrayList<MyInputDto>();
                            for (SearchHit searchHit : response.getHits()) {
                                if (response.getHits().getHits().length <= 0) {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                MyInputDto user = new MyInputDto();
                                user.setId(searchHit.getId());
                                user.setMessage((String) searchHit.getSource().get("message"));
                                chunk.add(user);
                            }
                            return new PageImpl<MyInputDto>(chunk);
                        }
                    });
            if (page != null) {
                sampleEntities.addAll(page.getContent());
                hasRecords = page.hasNextPage();
            } else {
                hasRecords = false;
            }
        }
```

What is the issue here ?
Is there any other alternative to achieve this?
I will be thankful if somebody could tell me how this ( code ) is working in the back end.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1**

If you want to use `ElasticsearchTemplate`, it would be much simpler and readable to use `CriteriaQuery`, as it allows to set the page size with `setPageable` method. With scrolling, you can get next sets of data:

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(Criteria.where("productName").is("something"));
criteriaQuery.addIndices("prods");
criteriaQuery.addTypes("prod");
criteriaQuery.setPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 1000));

ScrolledPage<TestDto> scroll = (ScrolledPage<TestDto>) esTemplate.startScroll(3000, criteriaQuery, TestDto.class);
while (scroll.hasContent()) {
    LOG.info("Next page with 1000 elem: " + scroll.getContent());
    scroll = (ScrolledPage<TestDto>) esTemplate.continueScroll(scroll.getScrollId(), 3000, TestDto.class);
}
esTemplate.clearScroll(scroll.getScrollId());
```

**Solution 2**

If you'd like to use `org.elasticsearch.client.Client` instead of `ElasticsearchTemplate`, then `SearchResponse` allows to set the number of search hits to return:

```
QueryBuilder prodBuilder = ...;

SearchResponse scrollResp = client.
        prepareSearch("prods")
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setSize(1000)
        .setTypes("prod")
        .setQuery(prodBuilder)
        .execute().actionGet();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<TestDto> products = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    do {
        for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
            products.add(mapper.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), TestDto.class));
        }
        LOG.info("Next page with 1000 elem: " + products);
        products.clear();
        scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
    } while (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception while executing query {}", e);
}
```

Comment: I am following the 1st appraoch but the pagination is not working. Its returning proper size but always from page 0. If there are 55 documents and i set page=5,size=10 i am still getting 1st 10 documents instead of last 5 documents